# remove elements from front of Buffer node.js

Tags: node.js, buffer, slice, splice, array-splice

I know there is a function called `slice()` but I am looking for `splice()` and that function doesn't exist how would I go about doing it some other way?

```
var buffer = new Buffer("090001060001020304090000060001020304", "hex");
var packetLength = buffer.readUInt16LE(0)
console.log('before slice buffer = ' + buffer.toString('hex'))
buffer = buffer.slice(0, packetLength)
console.log('after slice buffer = ' + buffer.toString('hex'))
```

the output I get is

```
before slice buffer = 090001060001020304090000060001020304
after slice buffer = 090001060001020304
```

But i need to get

```
before slice buffer = 090001060001020304090000060001020304
after slice buffer = 090000060001020304
```

the front 9 bytes should get removed and the bytes after it should be moved to the front how do I do this easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the starting point of your buffer to be offset by 9 instead of starting from 0

`let newBuffer = buffer.slice(9).toString('hex')`

Comment: cool thats even better then have I have done, can't believe I overlooked this

Answer (score 0):

Solved it..

```
console.log('before slice buffer = ' + buffer.toString('hex'))
var newBuffer = new Buffer(buffer.length - packetLength);
buffer.copy(newBuffer, 0, packetLength, packetLength + buffer.length);
console.log('after slice buffer =  ' + newBuffer.toString('hex'))
```

```
before slice buffer = 090001060001020304090000060001020304
after slice buffer =  090000060001020304
```